# Why does Netbeans "Initialization hint" say that the call to zapOperatorBooleans() is a Problematic call to constructor?

Tags: java, netbeans

If I insert the following before "`public GUI()`" the warning goes away but what's up?

```
  @SuppressWarnings("OverridableMethodCallInConstructor")
```

What should I REALLY do? And why?

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  boolean plusActive;
  boolean minusActive;
  boolean timesActive;
  boolean divActive;
  boolean toTheActive;

  public GUI() {
    initComponents();
    zapOperatorBooleans();
  }

  public void zapOperatorBooleans(){
    plusActive = false;
    minusActive = false;
    timesActive = false;
    divActive = false;
    toTheActive = false;
  }
  ...
```

I just read (in Tools>Options>Hints) that "Calling methods that can be overridden can be dangerous in the contructor because in the moment when the overridden method is called the object is not fully initialized" but that doesn't help me decide what I should do.

Comment: What do you think the warning message (hint) means? What don't you understand?

Comment: Calling non private methods from a constructor is a risky thing to do. The compiler is asking if you really want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `zapOperatorBooleans` as `final` or `private`. As to why, see http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=215

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis--Do you think you made an excellent point? Do you think you helped? Why am I asking these questions?

Answer (score 0):

All the comments helped. Here's the modified code. I only had what I had before because GUIbuilder tempted me with its initComponents() method and I lunged at the chance and fell off the ledge.

```
class...
      private static boolean plusActive = false;
      private static boolean minusActive = false;
```

etc.

```
  public GUI() {
    initComponents();
  }

  private void zapOperatorBooleans(){
    plusActive = false;
    minusActive = false;
```

etc.
(Not redundant; one or more of those booleans get set to true during iterated executions of the GUI and need to be reset, but they need initial values, too.)

So THAT'S what I REALLY should have done.

More importantly (from my standpoint), my ignorance of such a fundamental concept and others (e.g., my clueless response to the error message "Non-static ... may not be referenced from a non-static context") made me do quite a bit of reading, reflecting (personal, not Java), Googling, studying, thinking... and I am far better off than I was.